# Invalid or unexpected token in creating model with Sequelize-cli

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I`m in the right path, but it is resulting in error

Windows command line:

```
npx sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string,password:string
```

output:

```
Invalid or unexpected token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to execute the `init` command:

`$npx sequelize-cli init`

Second, your syntax is wrong. It should be:

`$ npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string`

Your syntax is just `$npx-sequelize mode:migrate` it lacks `-cli`

Comment: Please read the manual on sequelize https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html

Answer (score 3):

Check your .sequelizerc

```js
const path = require('path')

module.export = {
    'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error (and I know this is uncommon, but it might be useful) it turned out I was running `node v6.13.4`. The reason is because I am using `nvm` and that defaults to that `node` version.

Check the version of node that you are using

```
node --version
6.13.4
```

If you are not using `nvm`, update your version of `node` by [some](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) [method](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/). If you are, you can just tell `nvm` to fix it.

```
nvm install stable
nvm use stable
```